# Question Regarding XPath Selectors (For Scrapy)

Tags: python, scrapy, web-crawler, screen-scraping

Objective: Scraping the text data from the div class `list_area daily_all`.

Using the [scrapy shell](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/shell.html), I have first "scraped" the website I want to scrape data from:
https://comic.naver.com/webtoon/weekday.nhn

Using the 'scrapy shell' script:
`scrapy shell 'https://comic.naver.com/webtoon/weekday.nhn'`

And using xpath, I want to scrape all the text data from the div class "list_area daily_all":

```
response.xpath("//div[@id='wrap']/div[@id='container']/div[@class='list_area daily_all']/text()")
```

However, the above code does not return anything.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Since `div[@id='container']` and `div[@class='list_area daily_all']` are not parent and child, you will not get object.

Add one more slash and you will succeed:

```
In [1]: response.xpath("//div[@id='wrap']/div[@id='container']//div[@class='list_area daily_all']")
Out[1]: [<Selector xpath="//div[@id='wrap']/div[@id='container']//div[@class='list_area daily_all']" data=u'<div class="list_area daily_all">\r\n     '>]
```

Same for text. You choose very big block and it has a lot of tags and text in them. You can select all texts like here:

```
In [2]: response.xpath("//div[@id='wrap']/div[@id='container']//div[@class='list_area daily_all']//text()")
Out[2]: 
[<Selector xpath="//div[@id='wrap']/div[@id='container']//div[@class='list_area daily_all']//text()" data=u'\r\n                \r\n\t\t\t\t'>,
 <Selector xpath="//div[@id='wrap']/div[@id='container']//div[@class='list_area daily_all']//text()" data=u'\r\n\t\t\t\t\t'>,
...
```

Or be more precise in your selector.

Comment: Thank you, I now fully understand how this xpath stuff works.